# Вывести в PHP скрипте модуль Joomla со своими параметрами

Tags: php, joomla

Необходимо динамически вызывать модуль, но с разными параметрами. Возможно ли это в Joomla?
Нашел вот такой код, которы выводит те самые параметры:

```
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_name');    
$moduleParams = new JRegistry();    
$moduleParams->loadString($module->params);    
$param = $moduleParams->get('param_name');
```

А как их задать при вызове модуля нигде нет.

Joomla 2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//  Загружаем модуль марок
#-----------------------------
$module_avto = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_catalog');
$params = new JRegistry;
$params->loadString($module_avto->params);

$params->set('path', $this->path );
$params->set('typeview', 'marks' ); 

$module_avto->params = $params->toString('JSON');

$mod_catalog_avto = JModuleHelper::renderModule($module_avto);      
#-----------------------------
```